# Dipole moment induced in a spherical particle

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, capacitance, dipole, dipole-moment

Consider a spherical metal particle made out of gold.

If there is an external charge somewhere near the gold particle, is there a way to calculate the resulting dipole moment that is induced by the external charge? Or is there a way to calculate the induced dipole moment that results from an external dipole moment instead of an actual charge? Would be glad if you could give me some ideas or equations to tackle these two problems.

Comment: This might be of help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges#Reflection_in_a_conducting_sphere

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in the "polarizability" of the sphere. This relates the external field to the induced dipole moment. For a (ridiculously) rigorous treatment, a good book is "The Scattering of Light by Small Particles" by Craig Bohren.

However, if you're looking for a simple result, the polarizability and the dipole are related like this:

$p = \alpha E$

where $\alpha$ is the polarizability and in the case where the wavelength of light is much bigger than the sphere itself it's given by:

$\alpha = 4 \pi r^3 \frac{\epsilon - 1}{\epsilon + 2} $

where $r$ is the radius and $\epsilon$ is the dielectric constant of the sphere.

So to work out the induced dipole of the sphere because of whatever charge/dipole you've externally, first find the field at the sphere's position (via Coulomb's Law etc etc), then just apply the equation above.

Good luck!

Comment: a few questions about this what do you mean by wavelength of light(there is no light there, so I do not know what you actually mean). Then there is a term that contains the dielectric constant, but actually, this quantity is infinite for metals. so what does that mean?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry - I've always thought about this in relation to light. In your case with static fields, the equation above should always apply. The problem with light is the varying field meaning that if the particle is sufficiently large, the field could be pointing one direction on side of it and the opposite direction on the other side of the sphere. Not a problem for you though so the expression should always hold.

Comment: As for the dielectric constant, a perfect conductor does indeed have epsilon as negative infinity. Actual metals tend to have large negative values (say around -1000). In any case, the fraction cancels to 1 (or near as dammit) and so you're just left with $4 \pi r^3$ - in other words the induced dipole depends on the volume of the sphere (makes sense) and the strength of the applied field (also makes sense).

Comment: well, thank you, but I looked in the booked that you quoted there and there they are talking about uniform fields, so I guess that your equation does not apply anymore as I am interested in the dipole moment caused by inhomogenous static fields.

Comment: And so it depends on the size of your sphere - if it's big, the equation won't hold, if it's small compared to the rate at which the field changes so that the field is "quasi" homogeneous (at least from the sphere's point of view), then it will be valid. If you're sphere is big, things get complicated very fast so good luck!